# Lipschitz continuous gradient and quadratic bound property

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

Let $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert$ denote the Euclidean norm. A differentiable function $f: D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to have Lipschitz continuous gradient with parameter $L > 0$ if
$$ \left\lVert \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \right\rVert  \leq L  \left\lVert x-y \right\rVert \text{for all } x, y \in D.  \tag{1}\label{1}$$
A standard result is that a function $f$ (not necessarily convex) with Lipschitz continuous gradient satisfies the following "quadratic bound property":
$$|f(y) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)| \leq \frac{L}{2} \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert^2 \text{ for all } x, y \in D. \tag{2}\label{2}$$

I am thinking about the converse, namely if a function $f$ satisfies \eqref{2}, does it necessarily satisfy \eqref{1}? In [http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf) (slide 17) it seems like if we for instance assume that $f$ is convex with co-coercive gradient, the quadratic bound property implies Lipschitz continuity of the gradient. However, without these assumptions I strongly suspect that \eqref{2} does not necessarily imply \eqref{1}.

Just for fun, I have (without success) been trying to come up with an example of a function satisfying \eqref{2} but not \eqref{1}. Can anyone provide an example of such a function, or motivate why it does not exist?

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227159

Comment: The question there is different, but the answer proves the implication (2) => (1)

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for. Is there a way to mark this question as solved? I am quite new to this.

Comment: @DanielCederberg little late to the party, but you can just add your own answer with daw's link (or daw can make the answer). Then, choose that as the correct answer to mark it as solved